# Question about safely starting and stopping docker container

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I'm learning to use RabbitMQ and I am hosting it in a Docker container on my laptop. I went this route instead of running it directly on my laptop because I also wanted to gain some experience with Docker. Is it best to start and stop the container on shutdown/startup or does Docker automatically start and stop the container for me? I'm having a hard time finding clear instructions on making sure the state of my container is maintained and ensuring the work I do in it isn't lost due to simple mistakes. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Docker doesn't start or stop the container for you. You have to manually configure it to start on startup and stop before shutdown. That said, I don't think the data persists in the container, so you will need to find a way to save and restore the state.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Do you have any resources you recommend for learning how to use and develop in Docker? I'm a CS student and will be graduating next year. We haven't discussed Docker any and I'm trying to prepare myself for the job market.

Comment: State is saved in Volumes, so you need to map what you need to save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it best to start and stop the container on shutdown/startup or does Docker automatically start and stop the container for me?

Docker will automatically start containers for you if you set an appropriate [restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/) on the container. In general, this means using the `unless-stopped` policy, as in:

```
docker run --restart=unless-stopped ...
```

Your container will but "shut down" when your system shuts down the same way as any other process -- your service will probably first receive a `SIGTERM`, and may later receive a `SIGKILL`. This is sufficient for most applications.

> I'm having a hard time finding clear instructions on making sure the state of my container is maintained and ensuring the work I do in it isn't lost due to simple mistakes.

Any data in your container will persist between a stop and a start as long as you don't remove the container. However, if you are generating data that you care about, your best choice is to mount a volume in the container and store the data there. This makes the life cycle of your data independent of the container, which means you can replace/upgrade your container while still preserving your data.

You can read more about volumes [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Using volumes effectively requires you to know where your application stores data. This will often be documented in the `README` for the image, but not always.

> Do you have any resources you recommend for learning how to use and develop in Docker?

The Docker documentation itself is a great place to start. Looking at the design of some of the official images can also be educational.